# REGEX: Select everything NOT equal to a certain string

Tags: regex

This should be straightforward. I need a regular expression that selects everything that does not specifically contain a certain word.

So if I have this sentence: "There is a word in the middle of this sentence."
And the regular expression gets everything but "middle", I should select everything in that sentence but "middle".

Is there any easy way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: eh, just copy the data to a string var and do a search/replace....probably cheaper than RE anyway.

Comment: Can this word occur more than once in the sentence?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for a single regex match operation to be discontinuous.

You could use two capturing groups:

`(.*)middle(.*)`

Then concatenate the contents of capturing groups 1 and 2 after the match.

You may wish to enable the "dot also matches newline" option in your parser.
See for example [Java's DOTALL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL), [.NET's Singleline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#Singleline), [Perl's `s`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers), etc.

Comment: When/if you do this make sure you enable the `.` to match newline characters as well.

Comment: That does not guarantee that neither capture group contains `"middle"`.  Should it?

Answer (score 1):

Positive lookaround is the way to go:

```
/^(.+)(?=middle)/ -- gets everything before middle, not including middle
```

and

```
/(?!middle)(.+)$/ -- gets everything after middle, not including middle
```

Then you just merge the results of both

Comment: When/if you do this make sure you enable the `.` to match newline characters as well.